# PHP 8 date week number inconsistent?

Tags: php, date, datetime, week-number

When I use `(new DateTime(time()))->format("W")` it sometimes returns the correct value (15 for time() = '1618404852'), but sometimes it returns an incorrect value (16 for time() = '1618404853').

Those timestamps are not exactly between two weeks, because using '1618404855' as a timestamp will result in 15 (which is correct).

My code testing this is:

```
echo (new DateTime("1618404852"))->format("W");
echo "\n";
echo (new DateTime("1618404853"))->format("W");
echo "\n";
echo (new DateTime("1618404854"))->format("W");
echo "\n";
echo (new DateTime("1618404855"))->format("W");
echo "\n";
echo (new DateTime("1618404856"))->format("W");
```

This results in:

```
15
16
16
15
15
```

which makes no sense to me.
Am I doing something wrong here?

I've tried this on a local php-Server (8.0.0), as well as on a different machine running apache-php (7.4).
Using a phpfiddle website results in the same problem.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: The answer marked as correct has answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying the full date for each example with format("Y-m-d H:i:s") reveals what's going on here ([demo](https://3v4l.org/08IZH)):

```
4852-04-14 16:18:40
4853-04-14 16:18:40
4854-04-14 16:18:40
4855-04-14 16:18:40
4856-04-14 16:18:40
```

The default constructor is trying to guess what your strings mean, and guessing that the last four digits are a year.

To force it to treat the strings as timestamps you can:

- prefix them with an `@`
- use createFromFormat with the 'U' format
- create an object and then call setTimestamp on it

```php
echo (new DateTime("1618404852"))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// 4852-04-14 16:18:40
echo (new DateTime("@1618404852"))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// 2021-04-14 12:54:12
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("U", "1618404852")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// 2021-04-14 12:54:12
echo (new DateTime)->setTimestamp(1618404852)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// 2021-04-14 12:54:12
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `@` before the timestamp, otherwise PHP parses the timestamp to an incorrect date

```
echo (new DateTime("1618404852"))->format("c"); // `c` is the ISO-8601
// prints "4852-04-14T16:18:40-08:00", the year 4852
```

```
echo (new DateTime("@1618404852"))->format("c"); // `c` is the ISO-8601
// prints "2021-04-14T12:54:12+00:00", correct year
```